# Would you ever favourite a question you down vote?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, bookmarks

Today, I came across a user who posted lots of question in 1 area with no attempts on any of them. Many of these were very good questions and have answers. I would certainly benefit from learning from them, on the other hand, the user clearly made no slightest attempts on what appeared to me assignment questions? As a consequence, I favourite questions I down voted. (Because someone already provided a good answer) just wonder if I am like one of the only people who have ever done this... This is somewhat ungrateful, I thought...

Comment: Certainly. I might want to check back on the question; or the answers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila i think this guy just downvoted 3 highest voted votes to take revenge lol...

Comment: Is a negatively voted question without an answer automatically deleted even if it is favored?

Comment: Related: [Why favorite but not upvote?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25295)

Answer (score 13):

From [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585):

> Marking a question as a favorite basically says that a particular user feels like watching that question. It's completely separate from the voting system

Being the only built-in way to keep track of changes to questions,  *favorite*  could conceivably be used for both good and bad questions. There are various reasons why one might want to follow activity, including edits, on a question.   One reason is that one may want to reverse downvote or retract closevote if/when the question is brought into shape.

Briefly put, I don't see a contradiction between downvoting and favoriting (=bookmarking) a question.

But in  your concrete situation,  given that

> Many of these were very good questions and have answers. I would certainly benefit from learning from them

I think  you could consider recalibrating your criteria for downvoting.

(This is coming from a user with [downvote per day ratio of over 20](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/154445/top-100-users-with-highest-downvotes-per-day-ratio), top on the site.)

Comment: Holy cow, man! 20 downvotes per day!

Comment: Yes, but i would down vote a question when the user made no attempt on a question i heavily suspect to be hw!

Comment: Jeeze, your downvote ratio is higher than mine!

Comment: @Lost1 That's your decision, of course. I'm just saying: if the downvotes led the user to stop asking questions, would you feel something is lost for the site?

Comment: Hmm, i will give that some thoughts.

Comment: @PostNoBulls, how many *upvotes* do you cast per day?

Comment: Actually, @PostNoBulls also has the prize for most [upvotes per day](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/edit/159456) as well.

Answer (score 12):

I do favorite things when there is the possibility that the person asking will delete the question. If that happens, I can see the whole thing, but only if I can locate it. So, at least a quarter of my favorites are very bad questions.

Answer (score -4):

I tend to downvote problems that look like they were copied straight from a textbook, like "Evaluate ..."  Doesn't mean the problem itself isn't interesting or I couldn't learn from it, in which case it would still be worth favoriting.  Or maybe a bad question has an insightful answer that would be worth referring to again.

Of course, if you feel guilty, it always helps to provide a reason for the downvote so they can avoid more downvotes in the future.

Comment: -1 This does not address the topic of  favo[u]riting downvoted questions.

Comment: @PostNoBulls I thought I had.  Downvote on etiquette, favorite it to learn from it later.  I also attempted to address your concern that the downvote might cause the user to stop asking questions.  They learn the proper etiquette to ask next time, you both learn from the answer.  Win-win.