# Is there any way to find and view a deleted question that I commented on recently

Tags: support, search, deleted-questions

Recently I commented on a question which was about tiling a 100 by 100 grid with a 1 x 8 square. (Actually to prove this was impossible.) One of our users posted a link to a very interesting looking paper on tiling problems as a comment, and I also commented, but now looking through my comments I can't find the post. I assume it was deleted. However, I really want to find this paper! I had planned on giving a talk about it next week. Is there any way for me to locate the question?

Comment: Does it appear in [the list of recently deleted posts](http://math.stackexchange.com/tools)? If all you did was comment on it I doubt that's possible, but perhaps a mod can help you.

Comment: One's browser history is a place to look, too.

Comment: @quid I hadn't thought of that, though it is obvious in retrospect.

Comment: The result seems to me the sort of high-quality content we want to curate, although the Question is of the no-effort stripe we want to discourage.  In order to have our content and discouragement too, I posted a Community Wiki Answer quoting the relevant proof from Klarner's paper.

Comment: A more modern paper on tiling questions, which incorporates work of Conway and Lagarias, can be found at http://www.cflmath.com/Research/Tilehomotopy/index.html. "Tile Homotopy Groups" by Michael Reid. It's a well-written and fascinating paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it's [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436647/tiling-problem-related-to-algebra), and it's about [Klarner's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KlarnersTheorem.html), [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9800(69)80044-X)?

Answer (score 3):

If a Question is self-deleted by the poster, it will *not* show under the 10K User Tools report of [recently deleted items](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools).  Also the items shown are limited to deletion actions in the past 30 days, if the date range selector in the upper right corner there is used.

Regardless, if one had the foresight or luck to "favorite" the item, the Deleted Question would still appear [in ones personal Favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97110/155839). Will Jagy [once described this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12301/3111) as a strategy for certain "very bad questions".

If the Question ID (number following "questions/" in the SE URL) is known (e.g. from ones browser history), the item can still be viewed by 10K users.  Some ideas for users < 10K [were discussed here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13328/are-there-some-possibillities-for-users-below-10k-to-see-deleted-posts-of-other).

There was a post not long ago here on meta.Math.SE about using a query feature for deleted items in SE Data Explorer's schema (apparently novel).  However I cannot find that post (which I commented on) and suspect it has itself been deleted.

Comment: Did you mean [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21352/how-many-posts-get-deleted-and-what-are-they)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Yes I did have that in mind.  Thanks.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, deleted posts also appear in [the list of close votes one has cast](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure) (with a red background), and also probably in the list of delete votes.